# Quero saber porque está dando este erro na variável?

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np      # conda install numpy
import cv2 as cv        # conda install opencv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from PIL import Image  # para rodar no console
def showfig(image, ucmap):
    imgplot=plt.imshow(image, ucmap)

    img = cv.imread("imgs/pfig01.jpg",0)
hf = cv.calcHist([img],[0],None,[256],[0,256])

plt.figure(figsize=(13,5)) 
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img,"gray"),plt.title('Input')
plt.subplot(122),plt.plot(hf),plt.title('Hist')
plt.show()
```

Está dando este erro

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-03db2af2cf65> in <module>()
      7 
      8     img = cv.imread("imgs/pfig01.jpg",0)
----> 9 hf = cv.calcHist([img],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
     10 
     11 plt.figure(figsize=(13,5))

NameError: name 'img' is not defined
```

Comment: Basicamente por causa da indentação. Você "cria" `img` dentro da `def showfig` (criaria, se chamasse a função). Só que tenta usar ela fora do bloco. Isso é chamado "escopo" da variável. Ela existe somente onde foi criada, em princípio.

Comment: Você definiu a variável `img` dentro de uma função, que por sinal nunca é chamada. Ela não estará definida fora dela. Aliás, está bastante esquisito utilizar vírgulas para separar as expressões. O que está fazendo aí é criar tuplas que não serão armazenadas. Se quer apenas expressões na mesma linha, use ponto-e-vírgula.

Comment: Por favor, leia o comentário do Bacco e nos confirme se todo o código apresentado deveria pertencer à função ou se realmente deveria ser fora como apresentou.

Answer (score 0):

img é uma variável local, ou seja, ela existe somente dentro da função que a implementa. Ela é criada quando a função showfig é chamada e deixa de existir quando a função é encerrada. Declare a variável fora do escopo da função para que ela possa ser utilizada globalmente.